# Blender compositing, blur node problem

Tags: masking, compositing-nodes, motion-capture, blur

I am using mask for motion tracking scene, and I want use blur for mask in compositing. what is problem: blender node is bluring mask and make it larger, that causes problem for me, is it possible to make blur inside region of mask? ( blured mask, but in mask area, not outside) Last image has red area, that shows how blur node make mask larger
Thanks
[image: MASK original]

[image: BLURED mask]

[image: BLured are is RED]

[image: compositing]

Comment: Erode and blur?

Comment: Thanks, good node

Comment: Just multiply the mask by the resulting blur. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Dilate/Erode node set to 'Feather' instead of a Blur. Setting a negative Distance will erode the edges based on the set Falloff - so it will always be within the region of the mask. For more control of the falloff, set the Falloff of the Dilate/Erode to Linear and add a Color Ramp node or similar so you can control the falloff profile manually.

[image: composite dilate/erode feather]

Note the Split Viewer showing the comparison in the Image Viewer window between original (right-hand side) and 'feathered' (left-hand side).

Comment: Thanks a lot, erode node looks like good solution. Falloff node only available in shader compose, can't use for mask, but erode and color ramp is enough.

Comment: @VladMarkelov by ‘falloff’ I meant the Falloff property of the Dilate/Erode node, rather than the Falloff node. Glad this helps.

Comment: understood about falloff, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Perform your blur, then apply the emission constriction by multiplying the mask by the result.